# Swift - Repeat same code in different classes with one changing item

Tags: swift, class, copy, paste

I have the same code copy pasted in different classes with only the name of the storyboard that changes. How can i do that in a way that i can reduce the copy/paste effect ? I have many many classes with the same code. Using Xcode 7

***EDIT***: I'm sorry. It's actually the name of a CLASS that changes. For example : " ... as! ViewController1 " .

```
let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey) as! ViewController1
```

Comment: " with only the name of the storyboard that changes"? I'm confused what kinda function that can be. are those classes in a same project?

Comment: If the different classes are the same internally but just have a different name, why don't you just use one type of class to handle all the uses you have?

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new class to use the repeated code. Create a function inside this new class using the name of the different storyboards. Such would be efficient

```
 class NewClass {

    func functionFromStoryboard(name: String) {
         // put copied code here
    }
 }
```

then when you're ready, just call it

```
 // in other class, 
 let n = NewClass()
 n.functionFromStoryboard("storyboardName")
```

hope this helps

Comment: I edited my question. Would you mind taking a loot at the edit section please ? I tried to put the type as AnyClass, AnyObject, UIStoryboard and String, but when i change the class' name to the argument variable, an error says: " ***  is not a type "